# Python - Addition and merging with an array

Tags: python, facebook, merge

I'm using the Facebook API to collect some data on mentions. I'm collecting the month and the amount of times a term (eg: banana) has been mentioned in a post. So I currently have data coming in that looks like this:

```
12, 0
12, 0
11, 1
11, 0
11, 1
10, 0
10, 0
10, 0
```

Each row represents one post. I want to merge the months (first column) and the number of times a term has been mentioned (second column) so it looks something like this:

```
12, 0
11, 2
10, 0
```

I tried putting the data in an array like so:

```
[12, 0]
[12, 0]
[11, 1]
[11, 0]
[11, 1]
[10, 0]
[10, 0]
[10, 0]
```

but was unable to figure out a way of merging and adding the columns. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: What data structure is your data stored in? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is a list of tuples or lists, then you can use a `defaultdict` and iterate over the list, e.g.:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for m, c in data:
...     d[m] += c
>>> list(d.items())
[(10, 0), (11, 2), (12, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there are tools available to merge based on the value in the first column, but you can get the values you want fairly quickly with a numpy array. For example, for all the November posts, first we separate the original array into only those that are from November and then sum up the values in the second column. Note that with this method, your original array doesn't even have to have the months in order.

```
import numpy as np
a = [[12, 0],[12, 0],[11, 1],[11, 0],[11, 1],[10, 0],[10, 1],[10, 0]]
a = np.array(a)
b = a[np.where(a == 11)[0]]
sum = np.sum(b, axis=0)[1]
```